# button turn sideways anchor

Tags: html, css, button, rotation

I have a button that I am quite content with, and it animates well. However, I wish to rotate it 90 degrees to have it face down instead. I used `transform: rotate(90deg);`. However, this sorta skews it and the button moves to the right when hovered. Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```css
button{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;

  
  word-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: word-spacing 200ms linear, background-color 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: word-spacing 200ms linear, background-color 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button>More →</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when hovered, the button moves a bit to the right. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found that is causing this kind of visual bugs is the way the transform origin is set.

In this case, you can set a `transform-origin: left` and it will make it transform correctly. Take a look:

```css
button {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: left;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: word-spacing 200ms linear, background-color 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: word-spacing 200ms linear, background-color 200ms linear, color 200ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button>More →</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to properly horizontally center this button, because its center is on the left of the button?

Answer (score 0):

It's shifting because of your `"word-spacing: 10px"` which makes the button translate in order to contain the new sizing of the letters